# Deployment of Dynamic pages in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have been working with the nuxt project. There is a reset-password page in that project whose directory structure is like below
src/reset-password/_token.vue
When I'm preparing it for deployment
This page doesn't exists in the production build. I'm using nuxt generate command and nuxt.config has target:'static' value
Since I cannot have a static page for this case, as you know token changes everytime user puts a forgot password request.

Comment: Did you tried `/pages/reset-password/[token].vue` as shown in [the documentation](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/pages/#dynamic-routes)?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that you need `target: 'static'` at all if using Nuxt3: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/deploy/static-hosting